# "A detailed description" vs "detailed description"

Tags: articles

> **Detailed description** of statistical methods for biological studies is provided in Section 10.

Should there be an article?

> **A detailed description** of statistical methods for biological studies is provided in Section 10.

I googled and [found](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/description) that "description" can be both count and non-count. In my case, either option seems acceptable. The first option seems to represent, I guess, a more loose set of sentences describing statistical methods.

Comment: After I posted my answer, I read the link you posted, and I don't think "description" is used how you describe in your first example. Could you expand on that part of your question?

Comment: "Detailed description" in the first example seems to indicate a technique (how you make a description rather than the description itself), which would be uncountable. "A detailed description" would refer to one actual description (of more than one possible descriptions).

Comment: The lack of article there would be unusual in speech but is not uncommon in terse annotation, e.g. *(For detailed description, see section 10)*. What we have here seems to be an inline annotation, which might have gone into a footnote, or been placed in parentheses, depending on house style/conventions.  https://books.google.com/books?id=5d_zAAAAMAAJ&q=%22detailed+description%22&dq=%22detailed+description%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWkNCw3tDRAhXE4SYKHXTSDJAQ6AEIYjAO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the indefinite article is required here. *Oxford Leaners Dictionary* doesn't give enough information about the noun. But if you read [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/description), the uncountable version only refers to an action of giving a written or spoken account.

Answer (score 0):

To me, the first example simply looks like they forgot a word, or that it's trying to sound really casual by omitting "a".

I would not have interpreted it as meaning a plural of any kind. It would have used "was" instead of "is" in that case.